# Which for loop header performs better?

Tags: java, for-loop, compiler-optimization

I see the following a lot in the Android documentation:

```
int n = getCount();

for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++) {
    // do somthing
}
```

But I'm used to seeing and doing:

```
for (int i = 0; i < getCount(); i ++) {
    // do somthing
}
```

I'm curious if one is more efficient than the other? What is exactly happening in these two scenarios? When you call `getCount()` in the second way, does the computer have to allocate another variable? Or is it simply a matter of code cleanliness or preference?

Comment: Trust the compiler, it'll optimize it. Don't waste your time.

Comment: If you have two horses and you want to know which of the two is the faster then *race your horses*. http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the `javac` compiler of JDK1.6.0_21 generates for the two cases:

**First case:**

```
int n = getCount();

for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++) {
    // do something
}
```

Compiled bytecode:

```
invokestatic example/Test/getCount()I
istore_1
iconst_0
istore_2
goto 10
... // whatever code in the loop body
iinc 2 1
iload_2
iload_1
if_icmplt 6
return
```

**Second case:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < getCount(); i ++) {
    // do something
}
```

Compiled bytecode:

```
iconst_0
istore_1
goto 8
... // whatever code in the loop body
iinc 1 1
iload_1
invokestatic example/Test/getCount()I
if_icmplt 4
return
```

It may seem that the resulting code is different, but depending on `getCount()`, the runtime may optimize the execution. Generally speaking, the first code seems more efficient, especially when `getCount()` does some complex operations to return its value.

Comment: What if getCount() utilizes a database query? Then you could potentially have 50 database queries in a row, versus just 1.

Comment: `getCount()` was a bad example, but it's still valid!.

Comment: @Compass Indeed generally the behavior may be different. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The First one is more efficient than the other.

In first scenario, you're calling getCount just once,while in second scenario you are calling getCount for every condition check,which increase the execution time of loop.

Comment: Can you explain how ? wouldnt it call getCount() n times in 2nd case ?

Comment: @Sumedh it's likely irrelevant. I'll bet you money that if you bench mark the two the difference between the two is going to be negligible to nonexistent.

Comment: now that the OP has clarified that getSize() was what he meant instead of getCount(), yes, the difference is very negligible.But if getCount(), or whatever the method it is, had been a complex one, there'd be a considerable difference.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is not performance, thought second can be slower because

```
public class stuff {
    static int getCount() {
        System.out.println("get count");
        return 5;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < getCount(); i ++) {
            System.out.println("loop " + i);
        }
    }

}
```

has output

```
get count
loop 0
get count
loop 1
get count
loop 2
get count
loop 3
get count
loop 4
get count
```

Do you see that getCount in the loop is executed multiple times? Why is it not an issue? How can you compare performances of different things? If behaviour does not matter, you can be happy comparing `nop` with `themostcomplexComputionInThe` world.

Comment: I guess a better example would be `array.length` instead of `getCount()`

Comment: @tambykojak `attayList.size()` bothered me alot until Java 1.5 introduced foreach