# Calling function in loop header

Tags: java, performance, for-loop

I always thought that if I call function in loop header like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < getCount(); i ++)
```

that it is cached. However, according to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28506401/which-for-loop-header-performs-better) it seems like it does not and that I should store result of call in variable before the loop.

What's the truth then? Does Java compiles both in the same result or does it cache the result in runtime?

Comment: You could easily confirm that by making the getCount() randomly return different values? My understanding is that the getCount() is called for each iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why the classic `for` statement should cache the `getCount()` value ?
Doing it would mean that it will not consider any new value returned by `getCount()` between two iterations.
It would produce inaccurate results.

So, of course, it doesn't cache `getCount()`.

In your case if `getCount()` is "expensive" to call and you don't want to consider change of the `getCount()` value during iterations, you should indeed invoke and store this value before the loop.

Maybe you mix with the enhanced `for` statement (`for (String string : strings)`) that may be more effective as it relies on an`Iterator` after compilation.
But it addresses another need since it iterates on an `Iterable` object and not according to a custom condition defined by the client as in your example.

Comment: Well I was thinking of some basic method that returns same value each time, but you're right that there's no way for compiler what exactly method does

Comment: "I was thinking of some basic method that returns same value each time". Anyway, even if you are iterating millions of times, returning an `int` field from a method is really cheap and the gain remains extremely weak. That's why it is not really a concern... but if the computation is "expensive" of course.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not cached. It is calculated on each time. You can implement your own cache if you like

```
int cachedCount = -1;
int getCount(bool useCache) {
    if (cachedCount == -1) {
        useCache = false;
    }
    if (useCache) {
        return cachedCount;
    }
    int count = 0;
    //Calculate count
    return cachedCount = count;
}
```

and then your `for` cycle:

```
for (int i = 0; i < getCount(i > 0); i ++)
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, confirmed my findings " the getCount() is called for each iteration"

```
package com.company;
import java.util.Random;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < getCount(); i ++) {
            System.out.println("i?" + i);
        }
    }

    public static int getCount() {
        int rand = Math.abs(new Random().nextInt()) % 10;
        System.out.println("rand:" + rand);
        return rand;
    }
}

Output:
rand:9
i?0
rand:9
i?1
rand:4
i?2
rand:0

Process finished with exit code 0
```